# 100 times more sex in paradise?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I find the following very concerning:

> A man will be given the strength of a hundred men to eat, drink, feel
>   desire and have sexual intercourse.
>
> “Verily, the dwellers of Paradise, that Day, will be busy in joyful
>   things” [Yaa-Seen 36:55]
>
> they said, (it means) they will be busy deflowering virgins.

Source: http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/10053

---

There are a million and one things which are so much better than sex, for me atleast.  So the paradise described above isn't very appearling, especially as you'll be given 100 times more desire.  That sounds like 100 times more desire will be forced into your mindset, so you will more or less be forced to have 100 times more sex.  What if you don't want that?  Does that mean your only destination is hell?

I'm heterosexual and being given 100 times the strength in paradise so you've busy deflowering virgins isn't appealing to me.  Am I doomed to hell?

I mean after reading that, paradise is starting to sound like hell, i.e. you will have 100 times more sex every day for infinity, you will eat 100 times more every day for infinity, you will drink 100 times more every day for infinity and you will have sex 100 times more every day for infinity, and you can't do anything else...

> The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   said to him: ‘The excretion of any one of them will be in the form of
>   sweat which comes out through his skin, then his stomach will reduce
>   in size again.’”

Watching your stomach increase in size because you ate 100 times more than you normally do and you drank 100 times more than you normally do, then watching your huge stomach reduce in size again, kind of sounds scary...

What I am saying is, where is the appeal in eating, drinking, and having desire for sex 100 times more than normal?  3 meals a day is plenty.  but 300 meals a day???  How long is a day in paradise anyway?  if it's the same as earth days than, I'm not sure how you're going to eat 300 meals, and deflower 100 virgins in 24 hours, where a day is 12 hours, I mean, that means you only got 1.8 minutes per meal and per virgin.  I'm going to have to assume that the days are much longer, otherwise it's going to be a bit rushed, virgins on a conveyor belt, virgin, meal, meal, meal, virgin, meal, meal, meal, virgin, meal, meal, meal, virgin, meal ... every single day for infinity...   Maybe the translation got mixed up or something, because that kind of sounds like hell.

I'm concerned because as a muslim, I noticed that those quotes are from the quran and sahih hadith.

Have I misunderstood something, or do I only think this way because only those who desire to eat 100 times as much, only those who desire to have 100 times as much sex get paradise? i.e. lack of interest in having sex 100 times more than I already do, do I lack such interest because I am going to hell?

I guess all this would make sense and would be very appealing to men who have little or no food/water on this planet, and have little or no sex on this planet.  Kind of seems like islam is geared for the poor.  If you're an average person who has got the basics in this life, and/or are rich, paradise based on the quoted text above doesn't sound very appealing.

It seems that everyone in paradise will be 33 years old.  I feel that it would be much nicer to be 4 years old again.  You have no concept of sex, no interest in sex, amazing imagination.  Imagine that in paradise, but what you imagine as a 4 year old becomes real, and you have angles playing with you.  That sounds more like a paradise to me than having to deflower 100 virgins every afternoon, kind of sounds a bit boring and is going to get a bit repetitive after a while...

Anyway, my question is, what if you don't want 100 times more food, 100 times more drink, 100 times more desire for sex, and 100 times more sex in 24 hours?  Will it be forced into your mindset so you like all that.

Comment: I'd vouch for *sex*, I don't care about the million other things you have in mind:)

Comment: @Noah, I did mention that above, i.e. if you don't get enough of something in this life, food, sex, etc, you will find extra food, sex appealing in paradise, so I understand fully why some would choose sex.  For me, sex (so over-rated)... been there, done that many times, want something more fun/entertaining/exciting, and I can think of so much stuff that it wouldn't be practical to write a list, all legal (even legal islamically).

Comment: A man asked the Prophet(SAWS) about camels in Paradise since he was very fond of the animal, & he replied to the effect that he would get it, & everything that his heart desires. In fact, a man will also ask Allah to be able to practice agriculture. So I guess it means you can get just about anything in Paradise. Perhaps you like sports cars, so you may even get your own Lamborghini there :) Sexual urge in humans is very strong & has tremendous potential to motivate, such that some men would even stake their reputations to get it illicitly. None can deny its motivational power.

Comment: Down vote from me, as the questions is very ambigious and lengthy. Questionare does not know what he wants to ask

Comment: @Najeeb, the motivational power of sexual urges is very powerful indeed.  If only people knew.

Comment: @Farhan, not true, the last paragraph is my question.  Everything above that is setting the scene.

Comment: Just to add to the already provided answers, I think you are just over-thinking all this. In Quran its mentioned "..therein all that one’s inner-self could desire, all that the eyes could delight in, and you will abide therein forever." if you read it again, you will realize that you will get whatever YOU desire. Also, in my opinion, I think if someone wants a challenge, they can turn on the 'Hard-Mode' or 'Legendary-Mode' and turn on a story mode where you play as the lead and your minions lay out the stage for you. Lol. That would be fun, no?

Comment: Imagine yourself within a video game with unlimited scenarios, unlimited side quests and the perfect story line and "Full HD Graphics, lol" and "Realistic"-combat. :D The story unfolds as you make choices and you can level up etc. Maybe you will be able to call in your friends for a Multiplayer Experience and have a lot of fun. Hehe! Sorry. I got carried away. I just love games and I believe that we will get all this in the Jannah as it has been said many times that we will get WHATEVER we desire, so why not. :D If you want a little challenge, you got it, son!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having 100 times the strength one has in this life does NOT mean being bound to 100 times more eating/sex/whatever.

This just describes the capability of those in paradise - being capable to do something does NOT mean having to do it... almost every human being from a certain age on is capable to murder, yet murdering is NOT what most people do.

There is a Hadith in which the Prophet (PBUH+SAWS) says:

> If Allaah admits you to Paradise, you will have there whatever your
>   heart desires.

This basically means that you are NOT forced to do anything you don't want (like eating more...).

Another quote from Quran[al-Zukhruf 43:71]

> ...therein all that one’s inner-self could desire, all that the eyes
>   could delight in, and you will abide therein forever.

For further reading see:

- http://www.onislam.net/english/ask-about-islam/faith-and-worship/islamic-creed/460185-pur-wishes-and-heaven.html
- http://www.islamqa.com/en/20286
- http://www.islam-qa.com/en/1141

Answer (score 4):

You have misunderstood the true concept of Jannah, it will be a place of eternal bliss. This will include having your desires totally fulfilled to the maximum.
The inhabitants will have pleasure beyond measure, eating,drinking,treasures,palaces and even sex with luscious virgins. 
And it will be magnificent and perfect complete with out any dissatisfaction. No one will be able to compare it and that's is what seems to be your problem in understanding.As the joy will be out of this world.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. As to your post you might considera dding evidences to support your claims and see [answer].

Answer (score 1):

The way you picture paradise. Is Picturing having the best & everything of this world first and then thinking it is infinity times better in paradise. So much better that your mind does not have the ability to comprehend.

It is impossible to comprehend Jannah with the criteria of this world. A baby in the mother’s womb cannot comprehend what is told about this life; similarly, the world is just like a womb for us when compared with Jannah. It is impossible for us to comprehend it. That is why a baby, who is nourished with the umbilical cord in the womb, starts to benefit from life with his/her eyes, ears, mouth and many other organs.

Answer (score -2):

You won't be forced into anything in the Paradise. A Paradise is a place what any person can think of as the best place ever can be. Each person that is eligible to go to paradise has it's own paradise depending upon it's thinking about what the paradise should be. Since, Eating, Drinking and Sexual intercourse is the most common Human desire, that's why those are the points which are highlighted in the Quran and Hadith to lure people to do good acts in search of Paradise. And obviously you can have anything you want in your paradise, so your paradise will look like the exact way you think of a paradise should be. 
***And ALLAH knows the best***

Comment: Since you presumably haven't been to Paradise to witness this yourself, this post is in serious need of authoritative references.  Please see also the meta discussion at http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/598/22